# How to list all RPI frequencies' settings?

Tags: terminal, config.txt, overclocking, measuring, processor-speed

I've been playing with overclocking in the last 2 days. I'm helping myself with [this list](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md).

Yesterday I came across a command which lists all of these parameters and the frequencies which are currently set for the parameters. The output looked something like this:

```
arm_freq      1400 MHz
core_freq     400 MHz
h264_freq     300 MHz
isp_freq      300 MHz
v3d_freq      300 MHz
gpu_freq      400 MHz
gpu_freq_min  250 MHz
...
```

It doesn't actually tell me what the *current* frequencies are, just the min/max settings.

I cannot find the command anywhere. I searched through my browser history (can't find it) and through my commands history on my RPI - it's not there anymore.

Does anyone know what was the command I used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for src in arm core h264 isp v3d uart pwm emmc pixel vec hdmi dpi ; do \
    echo -e "$src:\t$(vcgencmd measure_clock $src)" ; \
done
```

Not that knowing these is of much practical use. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/vcgencmd.md

`vcgencmd get_config int | grep freq`

might produce a more usable list.